# HtmlAgilityPack search url link

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I create a `WindownsFormApplication` for a group of friends.  I'm using `HtmlAgilityPack` for my application.

I need to find all version of `taco addon`'s , like this:

```
<li><a href='https://www.dropbox.com/s/nks140nf794tx77/GW2TacO_034r.zip?dl=0'>Download Build 034.1866r</a></li>
```

Additionally, I need to check the latest version for downloading the file with the url as in the code below:

```
public static bool Tacoisuptodate(string Version)
    {
        // Load HtmlDocuments 
        var doc = new HtmlWeb().Load("http://www.gw2taco.com/");
        var body = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body").Single();
        // Sort out the document to take that he to interest us
        //SelectNodes("//div"))
        foreach (var node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div"))
        {
            // Check for null value
            var classeValue = node.Attributes["class"]?.Value;
            var idValue = node.Attributes["id"]?.Value;
            var hrefValue = node.Attributes["href"]?.Value;

            // We search <div class="widget LinkList" id="LinkList1" into home page >             
            if (classeValue == "widget LinkList" && idValue == "LinkList1")
            {

                foreach(HtmlNode content in node.SelectNodes("//li"))
                {
                    Debug.Write(content.GetAttributeValue("href", false));
                }
            }


        }
        return false;
    }
```

If somebody could help me, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

A single xpath is enough.

```
var xpath = "//h2[text()='Downloads']/following-sibling::div[@class='widget-content']/ul/li/a";

var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb().Load("http://www.gw2taco.com/");
var downloads = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath)
                .Select(li => new
                {
                    href = li.Attributes["href"].Value,
                    name = li.InnerText
                })
                .ToList();
```